Aggregation on an Array Column in BigQuery
I have 3 columns on my BigQuery table: column1, weight and vector. I want to multiply each vector with the weight on the same row and then group by column1.
I can multiply a constant value with an array column on BigQuery by:
SELECT *
       ,ARRAY(SELECT dim * weight FROM UNNEST(vector) dim) weighted_vector
FROM table1

But then how can I group by column1?
Input after element-wise multiplication with scalar:



column1
Heading 2




A
(4,6,8,2,1)


A
(2,4,6,10,7)


B
(11,43,3,1,90)



Desired Output:



column1
weighted_vector




A
(3,5,7,6,4)


B
(11,43,3,1,90)




Hi , can you share the any sample dataset.

Can you try something like this? Sorry I could not test as I dont have BQ
WITH weighted_vectors AS (
  SELECT column1,
         ARRAY(
           SELECT dim * weight
           FROM UNNEST(vector) AS dim
         ) AS weighted_vector
  FROM table1
)
SELECT column1,
       ARRAY(
         SELECT SUM(dim)
         FROM UNNEST(weighted_vector) AS dim
       ) AS weighted_vector
FROM weighted_vectors
GROUP BY column1 ```

Sorry, I may be missing something obvious, but where does 3,5,7,6,4 come from? I don't see how you get it from the two input vectors. What aggregation procedure are you envisioning/how do you want to combine multiple vectors into one vector?

Why don't you provide the source data?

Example is not very clear, where are the weights? not sure I understand how the result for A is calculated.
Please provide a better example so that we can assist you somehow
